# ng generate component giving error "Unexpected token / in JSON at position 629"

Tags: angular-cli

I just cloned an angular 6 project from bitbucket, did `npm install` and all the related tasks, it seems to be working well, but when I try to generate a new component using the angular-cli tool "`ng generate component`", I get the error

> "Unexpected token / in JSON at position 629"

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should the full error logs

Comment: Angulare CLI is a bit all over the place since the recent version 6. You can report this on their github, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: I had the same issue in Angular 6.

$ ng generate component Dashboard
Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1874

and I came here because I have no idea which Json file it is referring to. I looked through every single one outside the node folder and none of them are that long.

Comment: @IrishDubGuy's suggestion below fixed this issue for me, which was reading that angular-cli issues page.  Running my angular.json file through jslint (online) exposed an error in it.  Not on the line they suggest through.

Comment: Try validating you json file here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
If you have a problem with this fix it and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had same problem, when I trying to create component and after googling, I found  [https://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com) and which validate your JSON files and it points to the exact line and error.

For more information, please refer to following thread:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10880

Cheers!

Comment: Passing in my angular.json file in jsonlint helped me find the error. Thank you

Comment: This found a very obscure trailing comma, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 34):

Check if you accidentally made a comment.  Open up angular.json and look for '/' on the line or 'position' specified.  JSON does not support comments.

Comment: Thanks, man you are just life savior... I found I delete some lines which left over commas in json..and led to this error...

Comment: There are variations of this error with different positions numbers, it will be helpful to view the angular.json file in an editor with syntax highlighting to fix this error.

Answer (score 4):

Probably a problem in your angular.json somewhere, or maybe an encoding issue with the file or else a bug in Angular CLI. This is a reasonable place to start to investigate (one of the many Angular CLI github issues related to unexpected token errors)...https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10880

Comment: This suggestion led to the fix for me.  Running my angular.json through jslint exposed a problem with it (a comment inside it).  Removing that fixed the issue and I could then run ng generate component.

Answer (score 0):

I Just changed the encoding to UTF-8 of Angular-CLI.JSON using notepad++ and issue resolved.

[image: UTF-8]