# ng generate component giving "unexpected token [ in json at position 800"

Tags: angular

when i run "ng generate component " "unexpected token ] in json at position 800". When i type ng serve , the window is continuously running. any help please?
PS E:\angulartutorial\my-first-app> ng generate component about
Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 800
and when I run ng serve

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: One of your .json files is probably missing a closing `]` bracket somewhere. Start by checking your `angular-cli.json`, `package.json`, etc...

Comment: To make it quick share your `angular.json` if you are using Angular V6 or `.angular-cli.json` if Angular <=V5

Comment: http://collabedit.com/eqcjp

Comment: i have added the code in collabedit link. i do not know how to share the code as a url.. that is why i have shared in collabedit..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng generate component giving error "Unexpected token / in JSON at position 629"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257785/ng-generate-component-giving-error-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-629)

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer this for the benefit of searchers (and to confirm a statement in comments):

For me, the answer to this was an invalid character in `angular.json` (though someone else might find an issue in `angular-cli.json` or `package.json`, for me the culprit was `angular.json`).

Opening the file in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) helped identify the error (another editor thought it was valid).

In my case, the cause was that I had put a comment in the json.

E.g. In angular.json, this source provides the error:

```
"scripts": [
                /* boostrap.bundle includes popper.js */
                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
```

> ERROR: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 888

But remove the comment and it works e.g.

```
"scripts": [
                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: Just as an addition: The `angular.json` file will flag errors for things that might pass as valid JavaScript syntax. For me, I had the error `Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 986`, turns out it was because I had a `,` in between the last element of the array and the closing ] tag. So check for things like that too.

Comment: For me, it was the tsconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct `schematicCollection` in your angular.json

ie.

```
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "npm",
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular/material"
    ]
  }
```

in my last incident, I was still using `@nrwl/angular` and this was the culprit for me. After changing to `@angular/material` it was resolved.