# Angular service using command ng generate giving error

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using one `angular6` project where I want to create service/component using `ng generate` command but giving some weird and unspecific error

```
ng generate  service services/globalVariables
```

Error coming : 
**Unexpected token / in JSON at position 403**

Can we get some reason for this and which file has this Unexpected token '/' ?

[image]

Comment: Please note that you have folders already created as this command won't create the folder.

Comment: Yes folder is there

Comment: Without services folder same issue coming

Comment: Just want to know that: are you creating in the file in this directory tree like this src/app/services directory.???

Comment: Yes, its same directory src/app/services

Comment: Even creating component is giving same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628112/4299820 check this. You may have comment in your angular.json

Comment: Oh sir!! , That was the issue..... Thanks, But people has made question as  duplicate

Comment: Yes, why not  ....

Comment: oops :( I can't answer as It is marked as duplicate. Though it is not duplicate :(. Anyways glad to know your issue got resolved :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan : Can you please reopen this ?  This is not duplicate

Comment: @Sajeetharan : Yes , its duplicate of above one.   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257785/ng-generate-component-giving-error-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-629/50628112#50628112)

Accidentally made a comment. Open up angular.json and look for '/' on the line or 'position' specified. JSON does not support comments.